# Are default error pages available as JSON in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, custom-error-pages

When you create a new Rails application, it comes with built-in error pages for certain error codes, 404, 422, 500 etc. Is there any built-in mechanism I can use to provide these errors (and others) as JSON or do I need to manually define each individual error in JSON?

Answer (score 0):

for the Rails built-in pages you cannot do it because they are static inside public folder, but you can do something like:

```
# for 404
def not_found
  # render what ever you like 404
end

# for 500
rescue_from StandardError do |exception|
 # Your exception handling code here 500   
end
```

inside you application controller

Comment: So there's nothing I can leverage to do this in a generic way instead of manually handling 400, 401, 403, 404, 405, 406, 422, etc.?